# Not sure why this update_attribute isn't working for my token change on session#destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hope small pictures are okay!

[image: the console when debugging with pry]

as you can see the update doesn't work.  Here's the model, maybe you can tell me why it's not working.

**session.rb**

```
module CWB
  class Session < CWB::Resource
    def self.authenticate(name, password)
      account = CWB::Account.find_by_name(name)
      account if BCrypt::Password.new(account.password_hash) == password
    end

    def self.reset_auth_token(session_token)
      account = CWB::Account.find_by_token(session_token)
      new_token = SecureRandom.hex
      binding.pry
      account.update_attribute(:token, new_token)
    end
  end
end
```

**account.rb**

```
require 'bcrypt'

module CWB
  class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    include BCrypt
    attr_accessor :password
    validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password, on: :create
    before_save :encrypt_password
    before_create :set_auth_token

    private

    def set_auth_token
      return if token.present?

      begin
        self.token = SecureRandom.hex
      end while self.class.exists?(token: token)
    end

    def encrypt_password
      return false unless password.present?
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `encrypt_password` callback on the `CWB::Account` model is returning false and rolling back the save. This is because you're not passing anything in to your `password` attribute, so `password.present?` is false.

You should probably just return true if no password is supplied, so that you only do the encryption and password update if you're passing a password in.